# SSRS Send mail on click without opening Outlook

Tags: email, reporting-services

I have made a report with textbox which when it is clicked, Outlook is opened and I can send a mail (parameters like subject and body are set). How can I make sending a mail automatic? Without clicking 'Send' button on opened Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

You could send the mail from the server instead of from the client.
Therefore you can configure Database Mail in the SQL Server. Then you can send mails using stored procedures. You can trigger that procedure using a dataset of a subreport.

But what is your use case? Sharing reports? I think there a nicer solutions for that.